# Write a Sieve (language) filter to search an body and header of a message for a list of strings

Tags: sieve-rules

I have the following rule in [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_(mail_filtering_language)) to filter out messages containing various words in foreign languages:

```
if body :raw :contains [
  "choix",
  "comprovante",
  ...                                # various words elided
  "soldes",
  "visualizar esta mensagem"
 ]
{
  fileinto "ForeignSpam";
}
```

This checks only the body of the message, but I want to check both the headers and the body. I could write a similar rule that applies only to headers, but then I'd have to repeat the list of strings.

How can I write a single rule that searches an entire message (the body plus all headers) for any of a list of words?

Comment: Without even knowing what platform you're writing it for I'd assume magic.

Comment: Sieve is standardized. Why would the answer be platform-specific?

Comment: Because your wording doesn't make obvious that you're talking about [Sieve (mail filtering language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_(mail_filtering_language)) and not just talking about an algorithm using [Sieve theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_theory).

Comment: As for what you can do, look into [RFC 5229: Variables Extension](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5229.txt) and [RFC 6609: Include Extension](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6609.txt), both from the official (?) [overview](http://sieve.info/documents).